# thunar custom action to print selected file path and simulate enter key press

Tags: thunar, mx-linux

I have a file zx-script.mjs

I need to write a thunar custom action that opens the terminal or konsole in the current directory, prints ./zx-script.mjs and emulates the enter key to run the script. How do I write this?